# how to create expendable ListView?

Tags: android

i want to create expendable `ListView` like this **images**

[image]
[image: image2]

when click on `ListView` a xcewwn showlike this tell me firsxt this is expendable `ListView` or drawer?  and how will i create like this screen help me please thank you.

below is my simple `ListView` how i make expendable ListView like this image

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lytContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtCopyright"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lytTitlebar"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listMainMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/background"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: tell me it is drawer or expendable listview?

Answer (score 0):

There is already an ExpandableListView view widget in Android that you can use, but it doesn't get you all the way to what you want. You'll have to create custom views for the group header (school name, in your example) and its children. Hook it all together with a subclass of ExpandableListAdapter and you should be well on your way.